# Automate the archiving of Evernote notes on archive.is?

Tags: automation, evernote

I have a shared Evernote notebook which I use to collect news articles for a project that I'm working on. A couple of times a week I work through the notebook and run the webpages that new notes are pointing at through archive.is, a website that takes a snapshot of webpages. This means that if the original article is changed or deleted I retain a copy of the original.

Is there a way to automate this process, so that whenever I add a note to a specific Evernote notebook, the link that note is taken from is run through archive.is and, ideally, the link that archive.is then generates is appended to the Evernote note? Maybe via a userscript, or via IFTTT?

Comment: I've given the author a heads up to this page in http://blog.archive.is/ask.